# UIPopoverController, Xcode 6, IOS 8 using Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uipopovercontroller, xcode6gm

I'm having some trouble getting a UIPopover to appear using swift.  The code that is commented out works fine in Objective-C, but doesn't work using Swift. When I tap the + in my view controller I do get the "click" in my debugger, however no popover appears.

```
class PlayerInformationTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var addBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!

    var playerInformationViewController = PlayerInformationViewController()
    var popover:UIPopoverController?    = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /*

        //setup the popover
        _cuesPopoverViewController          = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CuesPopoverViewController"];
        self.cuesPopover                    = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_cuesPopoverViewController];
        self.cuesPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(540, 300);
        self.cuesPopover.delegate           = self;

        */

    playerInformationViewController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlayerInformationViewController")
    popover?.contentViewController = playerInformationViewController
    popover?.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 300)
    popover?.delegate = self


        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

@IBAction func addPopover(sender: AnyObject) {

    println("Click")

    popover?.presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem(addBarButtonItem, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)

}
```

Solution

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

     }

@IBAction func addPopover(sender: AnyObject) {

    var popoverViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlayerInformationViewController") as UIViewController
    popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    popoverViewController.preferredContentSize   = CGSizeMake(450, 450)

    let popoverPresentationViewController = popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController

    popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverPresentationViewController?.delegate = self
    popoverPresentationViewController?.barButtonItem = sender as UIBarButtonItem

    presentViewController(popoverViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: You're using `?.` everywhere. This means that if something is indeed `nil`, you won't find out about that. As a first step in debugging, try to resolve the optionals (obtain their value with `if let x = ..`) and use that value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple example for iOS 8. Popover are presented using adaptivity apis in iOS 8.

```
class PlayerInformationTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{

   ...


  @IBAction func addPopover(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
    let playerInformationViewController =  PlayerInformationViewController()
    playerInformationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    playerInformationViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 300)



    let popoverPresentationViewController = playerInformationViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverPresentationViewController?.delegate = self
    popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
    presentViewController(playerInformationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }


  func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController!) -> UIModalPresentationStyle{
    return .None
  }

}
```

Comment: This works great, with a minor typo.                 popoverPresentationViewController?.barButtonItem = sender as UIBarButtonItem.  now that the popover "pops" why isn't it showing what I have in the interface builder?

Comment: The problem with this code above is that, I am instantiating a new viewController from the code. So, if you use storyboard to instantiate your viewController, that probably solves your problem of now showing the UI elements in interface builder.

Comment: How would I add         playerInformationViewController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlayerInformationViewController") to use my storyboard, and not create a new view controller?

Comment: Use     self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlayerInformationViewControllerIdentifier")
 if you are using storyboard for your application.

Comment: still shows a new UIViewController if I add self.storyboard?. the view controller that I want to use as the popover is PlayerInformationViewController

Comment: You might be doing something wrong. Is this PlayerInformationViewController being loaded from storyboard ?

Comment: Posted solution.  Thanks @insane-36

Answer (score 1):

Display Popover with contentView from xib

```
func showPopover(sender: AnyObject) {

    let contentViewController = UINib(nibName: "ContentVC", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as ContentVC
    contentViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover

    var detailPopover: UIPopoverPresentationController = contentViewController.popoverPresentationController!
    detailPopover.delegate = self
    detailPopover.barButtonItem = sender as UIBarButtonItem
    detailPopover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any
    presentViewController(contentViewController,
        animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

Next allows to make not full screen PopoverView on iPhone
for this do not forget to inherit MainViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate  and set delegate to PopoverView

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController!) -> UIModalPresentationStyle 
{
    return .None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `popover` is `nil`. Where are you assigning/instantiating it?

Try changing this:

```
popover?.presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem(addBarButtonItem, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
```

To this:

```
if let pop = popover {
    pop.presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem(addBarButtonItem, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
} else {
    NSLog("Error: Popover was nil")
}
```

I imagine you'll see that error message in your console. In the .XIB for your `PlayerInformationTableViewController`, do you have a `UIPopoverController`?

If so, you probably need to ensure that the `var popover` is either (1) being manually instantiated in your `awakeFromNib`, or that it's an `@IBOutlet` and is being connected properly.

Alternatively, can you simply use the `popover` already present in your `playerInformationViewController`?